# How can I create Report on Queues and queue members

Tags: reporting, queue

I want to create a report on Queues to get Queue name and Queue member name. How can this be achieved? I researched and found that this cannot be done using standard reports. I will need to create vf page and export it as excel? Any other solution?

Comment: I am getting queue members and inserting each in a custom object (Fields - Queuename, User). If someone removes a user from queue how can i check if this is removed(I would have to check both queue name and user) and delete the record from custom object.

Answer (score 1):

Create a report type, from setup. In primary object select Queue. And then you can create a report on Queue as below,

[image]

Comment: I am not able to get 'Queue' in Primary Object dropdown. Can you tell me which org you are using? developer? I want to use Standard Queues that we access using setup. This is not a custom object.

Comment: Hi, I am using the Enterprise edition. Yes the one I had showed here is the standard Queue object. Have you try going to the new " Report type" from set up and check for Queue.The standard Quese should be there.

Comment: Can you please clarify your answer? Because I am not able to see the Queue object in Report Type dropdown list, and also there is an idea post to this problem: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BqYaAAK

Answer (score 0):

I used Einstein Analytics to automate the extraction of a list of Queue and members associated to each Queue.
The 3 objects used are: Users, Group and Group Members.
Here is how the dataflow looks:
 [image: Dataflow]
This dataflow was then used to create a dashboard with a Table view of queue and queue members with filters. This list can be then be exported as an Excel or a CSV file as per the requirements.